# make PHP variable provide link

Tags: php, string, variables, hyperlink

to do

```
echo <a href='www.google.com'> google </a>;
```

I want to use a variable instead of "google", like this:

```
$linkName="google";
```

but I cannot do this:

```
echo <a href='www.google.com'> $linkName </a>;
```

So what I should do?

Answer (score 2):

It's so simple. All alternatives are working

```
echo "<a href='http://www.google.com'>$linkName</a>";
echo "<a href='http://www.google.com'>{$linkName}</a>";
echo "<a href='http://www.google.com'>".$linkName."</a>";
echo <<<HTML
     <a href='http://www.google.com'>$linkName</a>
HTML;
echo <<<HTML
     <a href='http://www.google.com'>{$linkName}</a>
HTML;
```

or even

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><?php echo $linkName; ?></a>
<a href="http://www.google.com"><?=$linkName; ?></a>
```

Comment: Add this to have a complete answer: <a href='http://www.google.com'><?= $linkName; ?></a>

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href='{$url}'> {$linkName} </a>";
```

or

```
echo "<a href='" . $url . "'> " . $linkName . "</a>";
```

or use heredocs (google it)

Answer (score 0):

use double quotes, variable replacement is done in it:

```
$linkName = "google";
echo "<a href='google.com'>$linkName</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic PHP stuff, so I'd suggest googling answers like these. But here's how you'd do what I think you're asking:

```
echo "<a href='www.google.com'>" . $linkname . "</a>";
```

or

```
echo "<a href='www.google.com'>$linkname</a>";
```

Comment: probably because of your user name or avatar.

Comment: It wasn't me, but I suspect it's because you're the third user who posted the same answer

Comment: The first three answers were posted within a few seconds of each other. It's quite understandable that kids get angry over such matters.

Comment: @Norce Don't worry, I have been downvoted too. However, the only angry here is you.